# auth::check() and auth::user() not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this Laravel app II'm adding middleware for restricting user based on userType:

Middleware/Client.php:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Auth;
use Closure;

class Client
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
       // $user = $request->user();
       
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->userType == 1) {
        return $next($request);
        }
        else {
        return redirect('/');
        }
    }
}
```

I also added this in kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    'usertype' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserType::class,
    'client' => \App\Http\Middleware\Client::class,
    'staff' => \App\Http\Middleware\Staff::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
];
```

but it's not working when I add this client in web.php:

```
Route::get('/client_profile','Client\ClientController@getclientdetails')->middleware('client');
```

It's going in else condition if I login. I tried printing $user but its returning null

update:

```
Route::get('/client_dashboard', function(){
  return view('client.dashboard');
 })->middleware('client');
```

authenticate.php:

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('admin.login');
    }
}
```

Note: I have 3 userType, 2 user staff and client working on api and admin is using basic Laravel auth

Comment: You can do the same on `AppServiceProvider`

Comment: try `middleware('auth:client');`

Comment: middleware('client') working but auth::check and user not working

Comment: are you logged in when you request `/client_profile` ?

Comment: when i'm not loggedin it redirect to / but when i try to login it still redirect to /

Comment: when i login it should check with db but Auth::check() && Auth::user()->userType == 1) this part not working

Comment: let me know if it works.`->middleware(['auth','client']);` or with `[ ]` `->middleware('auth','client');`

Comment: it not working its redirect to another login mention in authenticate.php

Comment: Look if you have set the middleware and when you are logging in, it will redirect to default `HOME` route, so you need to place your middleware on that route.

Comment: place your middleware on this `route('admin.login')->middleware('client');` and let know what is your default route ?

Answer (score -1):

`Auth::check()` && `Auth::user()` Will only work if you are authenticated (logged in).

If you are trying to use `Auth::check()` && `Auth::user()` in a Middleware while:

1. not logged in
2. trying to log in

It will not work because the request hasn't reached the required function to authenticate your log in request.

Only use the `client` Middleware when your **logged in** or else it will not work.

Comment: after login i have redirected to client_dashboard and as you can see i added client middleware but its not showing dahsboard its redirect to /

Comment: at that part auth::check and auth::user should be working and i'm using api for everything

Comment: Did you check if the user that is logged in has a `userType == 1` ?

Comment: yes userType is 1 but at that part its not getting any user i tried printing $user its returning null

Comment: If its returning `null` then you are not logged in the system.

Comment: without middlreware i can login

Comment: i removed everthing just doing this $user = $request->user();
        print_r($user);die; its printing null

Comment: Looks like your implementation of the Middleware or somthing related to it is causing the problem, try to restrict the user in the controller function your trying to protect.

Comment: okay i have figure it out the problem with request->user working with auth but its not working with api routes